# declare out parameter for custom object in spring stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, spring, stored-procedures, ojdbc

I have the below stored procedure with the IN OUT parameter as custom object. I want to get the data returned from the procedure and map it to the java object using spring Stored procedure.

**Stored Procedure parameters:**

> PROCEDURE get_prev_record (
>         p_curr_rec_i           SCRUM.employee_ot,
>         p_prev_rec_io   IN OUT SCRUM.employee_ot)

**Object Type declaration:**

> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CORE.EMPLOYEE_OT AS OBJECT (SCRUM.EMPLOYEE_ID
>   NUMBER (18), SCRUM.EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2 (30));

I define the below parameters using the classic stored procedure.

**Spring stored procedure parameters:**

> declareParameter(new
>   SqlParameter("p_curr_rec_i",OracleTypes.STRUCT,"SCRUM.EMPLOYEE_OT"));
>
> declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("p_prev_rec_io",OracleTypes.STRUCT,"SCRUM.EMPLOYEE_OT",new
>   SqlReturnStruct(Employee.class) ));

But the output is not returning any values from DB. When i change the SqlOutParameter to SqlInOutParameter, i get the below error.

"1 parameters were supplied, but 2 in parameters were declared in class"

Can anyone please help me on mapping the output data with java object.